Early/Mid 90s horror movie with child protagonist
I'm trying to identify a early/mid 90s horror movie with a child protagonist. I remember a scene where this child would see these creatures with glowy eyes that were living inside a vent or air duct, they would appear and his mom doesn't believe the child at first. I remember the kid in his bed sleeping and the creatures would come up at night from the air vent (those small spaces at the bottom of the wall). 
It's not critters or trolls, it was in English and from the US or Canada, it was shown on Cinemax at the time. And I remember that they wanted to possess the child or something.

You might want to provide a more descriptive question title

Could this be Stephen King's Cat's Eye? Specifically the third segment, "General" with Drew Barrymore.
Differences:               

from 1985 so not quite early 90's
little girl not a little boy
hole in wall, not air vent

Similarities:

in English, from the US
little creature with glowing eyes
mom at first doesn't believe the child about the creature
kid in bed sleeping, creature tries to absorb life force or "possess" the child


Hi I've looked up for Cat's Eye, but it's not the same one. Thanks for your response! I love Stephen King's novels.
